# Appending new columns to data table

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am working with data tables at the minute and finding it tough to append a new column. I have searched google for answers, however none of the suggestions seem to work for me.

I tried this sugguestion as but failed to get it to work with my code;

```
aoColumnDefs"
{
    "aTargets":[7],
    "mData": null
}
]
```

I have created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ns5F6/) to show my code, im sure this is something obvious.

Sorry if this is a silly question but it is wrecking my brain... always the small things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Melissa

Comment: question is dependent on when you want to add column. Prior to initialization ( on page load)? Or after? Also what is source of data in column

Comment: Prior to initialisation if possible, I just want to show hardcoded HTML within the the column. I hope this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
 <table id="tableCities">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>country</th>
                <th>zip</th>
                <th>city</th>
                <th>district code</th>
                <th>district description</th>
                <th>actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

You can define your columns in a different way like this:

```
"aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "mData": null }
    ]
```

or this:

```
"aoColumnDefs":[
    {
        "aTargets":[5],
        "mData": null
    }
]
```

Here some docs http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns, hope it will Help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however when I add this it seems to break all sort/search functionality. Do you have any idea why this would be?

Comment: Cool! Thanks a bunch, did you do anything differently than what you previously explained? Thanks again